# DateRangeInput - how to set the first day of last month as the default start date

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Looks like the default date is impacted by the minDate and maxDate value.

Here is the code.

```
<DateRangeInput
        formatDate={(date) => {
          return moment(date).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
        }}
        shortcuts={labels}
        minDate={getMinDate()}
        maxDate={getYesterdayDate()}
        onChange={handleRangeChange}
        parseDate={(str) => new Date(str)}
        value={this.state.range}
      />{" "}
```

The default start date is NOT this or previous month, see below.
[image]

**I want to show July & Aug as the default months. How to do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by setting initialMonth value.